# How Set authorization token dynamically to request in Axios, NestJs

Tags: axios, nestjs

How to set the authorization token dynamically to Axios per each request? Axios is used for requests forwarded from service to external services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to the headers via the options parameter

```
const res = await axios.get('https://httpbin.org/get', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ey…'
  }
});
```